# How to rename a Youtube video with Youtube Data V3 API

Tags: go, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am trying to rename a youtube video using Youtube API data V3 from Go client. Here is the code:

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"
)

var (
    client *http.Client
)

func init() {
    client = getClient(youtube.YoutubeForceSslScope)
}

func main() {
    service, err := youtube.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to create YouTube service: %v", err)
    }

    rename := &youtube.Video{
        Id: "someid",
        Snippet: &youtube.VideoSnippet{
            Title:      "Test Title",
            CategoryId: "27", // Education
        },
    }

    call := service.Videos.Update("id,snippet", rename)

    response, err := call.Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error making YouTube API call: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(response.Snippet.Title)
}
```

Here is the output:
`Test Title`

But when I check the video in youtube, it is not renamed.

Comment: Give YouTube's site some time to display the new title. To double-check the update operation, issue a call to the following URL: `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID&part=snippet&fields=items/snippet/title&maxResults=1&key=API_KEY`.

Comment: @stvar How much time would it take to reflect. It's been more than an hour after I made the request. There is no change yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot tell how much time it takes for the back-end to propagate the change in the system. A span of more than one hour indicates to me (am guessing here) a possible bug in the system. I'd recommend to file a bug report directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/). In any case, does the URL I posted above return a changed title? (That URL may well be issued within any browser upon replacing `VIDEO_ID` and `API_KEY` with concrete values.)

Comment: @stvar I see that my video is renamed now. It has taken around 12hrs to reflect. 
But it is quite surprising that it takes so much time with APIs. If I make changes in YouTube Studio Web UI, changes are reflected immediately. Why should APIs require so much time?

Comment: I cannot imagine that any video title update implies 12 hours for propagating within the system. If this would be so, then lots and lots of API users would have already been complaining here and on Google's issue tracker site. I still think that, in your case, it was some sort of internal bug (maybe a transitional one) that got fixed in the mean time by Google staff. I also guess that the YouTube Studio itself is using the same API (and back-end for that matter) when applying operations on video resources.

Comment: Also don't forget that the Google's system is distributed; hence inconsistencies within it can look quite strange from outside, when having no concrete knowledge of its internal functioning.

Comment: @stvar You are right! The same code works like charm now! Videos are being renamed instantaneously. Must be some internal issue that's fixed now.